# Numeric approximation for fitting a Gamma Distribution with a single parameter

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, polygamma, probability-distributions

Given a series of $N$ observations $\left(x_1, \ldots, x_N\right)$ that follow a Gamma distribution with a single parameter, $ \text{Gamma}(k, k)$, what is the maximum likelihood estimate of $ k $?. It should be noted that $k$ is both a shape and scale parameter, not a rate parameter.

My analysis boiled down to approximating the solution for the following equation: $$ \ln k + \psi(k) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N \ln x_i + \frac{1}{Nk^2}\sum_{i = 1}^N x_i - 1 $$
How should I estimate the solution for this equation?

Comment: The derivation of the first-order condition for an ML estimate of $k$ is correct. We then usually let the computers do the rest (numerical iterative solution). What is it that you are looking for?

Comment: I was looking for a simple non-iterative approximation. For example, when performing maximum likelihood for a Gamma distribution with 2 independent parameters, one can estimate with a single expression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\ln k + \psi(k) = E(\ln X) \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N \ln x_i $$

Substituting in the equation for the MLE, you have

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N \ln x_i = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N \ln x_i + \frac{1}{Nk^2}\sum_{i = 1}^N x_i - 1 $$

$$\Rightarrow 1=\frac{1}{Nk^2}\sum_{i = 1}^N x_i \Rightarrow \hat k = \sqrt {\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^N x_i }$$

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the clever machination I was looking for.